# ASPX page with spaces in URL cannot be read

Tags: java, asp.net, jsoup, spaces, urlconnection

I have a problem with spaces in the URL of an .aspx page.

I replace the spaces with replace(" ","%20")

When connecting via

```
Jsoup.connect(URL).get()
```

or

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) URL.openConnection()
```

I get the following error:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://www.fangraphs.com/boxscore.aspx?date=2018-03-29&team=Blue Jays&dh=0&season=2018
```

Problem:

The connection seem to take the %20 away (between Blue and Jays) and replaces it again with a space (I tried PHP pages and it works, so thinking it might be due to aspx pages)

Comment: 400 means Bad data(you did not passing required data)

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP response code: 400** means Bad request
that means you sending invalid data
 For Example Server Side want int data you sending double viceversa like that

So server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.

Comment: Hi Venki WAR, my Problem is that when connecting to the following URL, it works: https://www.fangraphs.com/boxscore.aspx?date=2018-05-14&team=Cubs&dh=0&season=2018 - only when connecting to an URL with a space it fails (e.g.like above between Blue and Jays) - I tried replacing the space with %20, which normally works, but here I still get the 400 error and the Url returned in the error is without the %20 - do you know how the connect will work?

Comment: But here it seems due to the space and that the HTTPconnection and Jsoup.connect() seem to revers the Workaround in adding %20 - do you have any clue how to solve this?